# ¿Cómo puedo forzar un salto de linea en php?

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Estoy generando un pdf con `mpdf` y al leer un campo de texto en `mysql` guardado con `texarea` con sus saltos de linea y tal no me lo mantiene.

Si leo el campo fuera de `mpdf` si lo hace, pero con `mpdf` se lo pasa por el forro y lo pone todo en la misma linea.

¿Hay alguna forma de forzar a php a que haga los saltos de linea?

He puesto:

```
preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'\n',$Datos["cliente"])
```

Pero ahora solo me añade .\n.

Comment: ¿Has probado con `"\n"` (entre comillas dobles) o `PHP_EOL` (como constante)?

Comment: cual seria la sintaxis? @OscarR

Comment: Puedes usar [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) por ejemplo. Los saltos de línea suelen ser `"\n"` o `"\r"`. Y los reemplazas por la constante `PHP_EOL` antes de pasarlo a la función. _Como norma general_, si lo trata como texto plano debería funcionar.

Comment: pasa olimpicamente @OscarR he editado la pregunta añadiendo lo que he puesto.

Comment: Primer comentario... `"\n"` (entre comillas dobles) si no lo trata como un `string` literal

Comment: con comillas dobles directamente pasa de todo XD @OscarR

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiarlos por saltos de línea HTML? `str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $Datos["cliente"]);` Si quieres dos saltos: `str_replace("\r\n", "<br /><br />", $Datos["cliente"]);`

Comment: Perfecto @A.Cedano ahora si va :) ¿me lo pones como respuesta oficial que lo de como solucionado?

Comment: Elimina entonces de la pregunta "_Es texto plano_" por que produce confusión. En texto plano no se puede reproducir un salto de línea de `html`.

Comment: @OscarR Los saltos de línea en texto plano son `\r\n` y precisamente por eso hay que reemplazarlos por `<br />`. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo sé. Al poner la referencia que es texto plano, ni si quiera me planteo decir nada de `html` ¿no? Igual ha sido una mala interpretación mía de la pregunta...

Comment: culpa mia @OscarR no he caido que lo que interpreta es html :_(

Comment: Sin problemas, lo importante es que lo has solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiarlo por saltos de línea HTML:

Un salto de línea:

```
str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $Datos["cliente"]);
```

Dos saltos de línea:

```
str_replace("\r\n", "<br /><br />", $Datos["cliente"]);
```

Comment: Mil Gracias :) funciona perfectamente

Comment: @Killpe  Me alegro :) Saludos.